# what is the easiest way to connect xe:restService to xp:repeat?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I would like to display view data via a repeat control and avoid simple data binding (perhaps I would like to display the data later not via an xpage, but for now I do).

what is the easiest way to bind the xe:restService (rest service control) to xp:repeat (repeat control)?

can I reuse the variable name for the rest service in the repeat control somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to read the Rest service and parse it out to a collection/ArrayList that gets passed to the Repeat. This article shows how to read a REST service using Java. http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=consuming-restful-data-in-java-with-authentication